# Ubuntu server resets to work only locally

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, wordpress

This is maybe a very stupid question as I am very new to this. Just lost so much time looking for the solution, but couldn't find any so far. So any tips would be appreciated.

My problem is with web server based on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-126-generic x86_64), which I use hosting my personal website and ftp.

I manage to setup everything (linux, apache, ftp server, mysql, php, wp, ufw, router, etc) and all runs perfectly. But after physical restart of machine something happens and it only works locally (website and ftp). Can't access server from outside. Nothing changed in router settings or firewall. Ports are still open. All works well after I reinstall everything from beginning. But this is not a great solution.

I guess there should be something simple, but couldn't find what it is. Hope you can offer any tips.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault.  What do you mean by 'only works locally'?   i.e.  locally as in localhost only, or local as in LAN only?   something must have changed.

Comment: @ewokx as in LAN. If I try to access outside my LAN it doesn't work. Says website is not reachable. The same for FTP. Something changed, but where to start looking? I checked several times router and ufw settings. They are ok. What else to look?

Comment: port forwarding on the router,   port changed on the web server?   if a full reset/reinstall fixed it, then it's apparent something in the settings had changed.

Comment: @ewokx ip and port forwarding didn't change. I can assess everything with outside ip or local ip, website name too, but only if I am connected in my LAN. From outside network get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.